# How do I prove that this is homeomorphic to Klein Bottle?

Tags: algebraic-topology

My professor is teaching quotient space recently and he gives very informal arguments (drawing diagrams, arrows and stuff). I think he wants students to get familiar with quotient spaces and visualize them.

> This is the definition of Projective plane:
>
> Set $x\sim x$ and $x\sim -x$ for all $x\in S^2$
>
> Then, $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $S^2$.
>
> Then $P^2$ is defined as $S^2/\sim$.

Then, he gave us an assignment that is:

> Let $D_1,D_2$ be open disks in $P^2$.
>
> Paste the boundaries of $P^2\setminus D_1$ and $P^2\setminus D_2$ and call it $V$ (That is, set them a equivalence relation)
>
> Then, $V$ is homeomorphic to the Klein Bottle.

How do I show this?

FYI, my professor define the Klein Bottle as the quotient space of $X$ where the equivalence relation is given by $(0,t)\sim (1,t)$ and $(t,0)\sim(1-t,1)$.

Comment: Moreover, I am not really sure what he meant by **open disk** in $P^2$. I don't think he meant $P^2$ is metrizable.

Comment: It is locally euclidean

Comment: I would draw the two $P^2$ as squares with identified edges, cut the disks off the disks, glue and compare with the square of the Klein bottle

Comment: You have not said what $X$ is in your definition of the Klein bottle.

Comment: @Lee Oh.. Right. $X$ is $[0,1]\times [0,1]$

Comment: Is it usual to do very intuitive and infornal stuffs (such as drawing..?) when studying algebraic topology first time?

Comment: Read the section of Munkres on quotient topology.  It won't be enough but it will get you started.

Comment: Proof by picture can be just as formal as a wordy, symbol-ridden piece of prose. In a geometric subject like topology, it's inevitable that you will use images to both guide intuition and illustrate otherwise-technical parts of a proof.